# Spring Component with JUnitTests

Tags: spring

I am using a Spring `@Component` which implements
`ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>`. This component runs on tomcat startup, but when I run the unit tests, it runs the Component again. Why is that happening?

Here is the component -

`BackGroundServices` implements `Thread`.

```
@Component
public class RunBackgroundServices implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    private final BackgroundServices backgroundServices;

    private ExecutorService executor;

    @Autowired
    public RunBackgroundServices(BackgroundServices backgroundServices) {
        this.backgroundServices= backgroundServices;
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {

        executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executor.submit(backgroundServices);
    }

    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextStoppedEvent event) {
        executor.shutdown();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can annotate the test like that

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { TestConfiguration.class}, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class MyTest{}
```

and then create your own configuration of jUnit tests when you can initialize only these beans that you want

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfiguration {
  @Bean
  poublic Xxx xxBean(){
  }
}
```